# Django -- relation " " does not exist

Tags: python, django, heroku

There is some funny stuff going with my database.

I am trying to create a new model but I get this error when trying to load the page:

```
ProgrammingError at /posts/
relation "new_sites_topichome2" does not exist
LINE 1: ...te_added", "new_sites_topichome2"."owner_id" FROM "new_sites...
```

Here is the models.py

```
class TopicHome2(models.Model):
 
title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
text = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'image/set/', null = True, blank = True)
urllink = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null = True, blank = True)

date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):

    return self.title[:50]
```

forms.py

```
class TopicHomeForm2(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta: 

    model = TopicHome2
    fields =['title', 'text', 'image','urllink']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TopicHomeForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter title here'
    self.fields['text'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter text here'
```

views.py

```
def new_topichome2(request):

if request.method == "POST":
   form = TopicHomeForm2(request.POST, request.FILES)

   
   if form.is_valid():
        new_post = form.save(commit = False)
        new_post.owner = request.user
        new_post.save()

        form.save()
        return redirect('new_sites:index')
else:
    form = TopicHomeForm2()
    
context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'new_sites/new_topichome2.html', context)
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I am using heroku and AWS buckets for static files. Is it possible that my database is actually stored in the AWS RDS?

I have a model called Books which has many entries/objects in it (all of the entries are shown on the website), but when look at model in the database through the shell it has only 2 entries in it.

Comment: Did you [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/) the changes to your database? i.e. run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: @elyas yes I did, those run fine.

Comment: Does this error happen locally or only when running on Heroku?

Comment: Only when deployed/running through heroku.

Comment: If you suspect the root of the issue is multiple databases, perhaps try finding the actual location of `db.sqlite3` used at runtime e.g. `./manage.py shell` and then `from django.conf import settings; settings.DATABASES['default']['name']`. Is it the same file that you're accessing through the `sqlite3` shell?

Comment: I ran the command, it seems to the same database located where my manage.py file is.

Comment: Can anyone help?